# Apps asking only permission to read external storage

Tags: permissions

Some of my apps only ask for a permission to read external storage, not to write. I trust these apps (even my banking app), so I guess they are not looking at my files. Any idea why they need this permission? Is this a useless permission?

Comment: at least my banking app wants me to save montly pass sheets pdf

Comment: Do those apps e.g. need to import things – like `*.csv` files with transactions with your banking app, which you mentioned as only example? Then this permission certainly is not useless.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly useless (unless the app has some feature to download your transactions etc to external storage) but alas you are helpless there not to grant it anyway. The app mostly would force you to grant it neverthless